# Tengo un JSON, y quiero desplegarlo en un ngFor ul<li

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un JSON en un componente padre

```
  stacks = {
    "HardSkills": [{
      "nombreTecnologia": "JAVA",
      "imgUrl": "path"
    }, {
      "nombreTecnologia": "JavaScript",
      "imgUrl": "path"
    },],
    "SoftSkills": [
      "✔️Trabajo en equipo",
      ]
  }
```

y cuando lo parseo  para enviarlo al hijo como OBJ,porque si lo envio tal cual, no se como inicializar la variable en el hijo. me muestra el siguiente error

> Argument of type '{ HardSkills: { nombreTecnologia: string; imgUrl: string; }[]; SoftSkills: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

100 stackObjt = JSON.parse(this.stacksJSON);

como podría hacer para leer este JSON?, ya que está compuesto de objeto {} y y array []

Comment: Agrega el código.

Comment: Incluye los `models.ts`